# Udate the webview content without update the webview component in android

Tags: android, webview

I have a questions about webview in android. I am using 9 tab, all tabs are fragmented with webview and navigation menu bar. When I click menu item in navigation menu i have to load fusion charts on webview. My question is can we update webview content without reloading the webview component when menu item selected??? now wen i select menu item it reload the all 9 tabs. I have to update content only not a webview component. Becuase it taking too much time delay..

Any1 please help me. I was running out of time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi pradeep u need to load the webview inside of the app am i correct

Comment: you are correct. I loaded the the web view with 9 tabs and and navigaiton drawer inside my app. Now i have to update the webview content without reloade the 9 tabs and webview when navigation item selected.

Comment: put web view client i think it will work

Comment: let me check with this....

Answer (score 0):

> here is the code for webview client

```
        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks... it should reload the contents from url. But i am load the datas dynamically and not from web. Can you help on this???

Comment: i cant understand u r requirement

Comment: Hi mohan.. Thanks for ur response. I have response data from webservice. When user select item on navigation menu 9 web views load the response data to display fusion charts. can u understand now?